# Можно ли в WPF задать триггер, на диапозон значений?

Tags: c#, wpf

Мне хочется сделать анимацию перехода в моем слайдере. Для этого мне нужно триггеру объяснить, что в такой то диапозон размера элемента, ты должен убрать картинку и поставить текст. Я пробовал разное, и ничего не нагуглил поэтому поводу.

Сейчас у меня стоит так

```xml
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ButtonBorder, Path=ActualWidth}" Value="48">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
</DataTrigger>
```

Я же хочу, чтобы при диапозоне ширины >48, у меня включался лейбл мой. Сейчас стоит одно значение 48. Как мне задать диапозон?

Comment: Нет, не можно, используйте `IValueConverter`.

Comment: Если я напишу код позади для конвертера, это будет нарушением mvvm?

Comment: Что в вашем понимание `код позади для конвертера`? Конвертор в WPF, это нечто такое `{Binding SomeProperty, Converter={Convertor}}`, где `{Convertor}` - отдельный класс, реализующий `IValueConverter`, у которого есть 2 метода (`Convert` и `ConvertBack`), в которых вы и прописываете логику конвертации текущего, привязанного значения в нужное вам для XAML и наоборот. Вот там вы и прописываете "если int > заданного, то true, иначе false", все, задаете в привязке конвертор, в триггере `true`, готово. Нарушает MVVM? А чем?

Comment: Спасибо, не ту статью значит читал. Там был класс в классе окна : Window я и его имел ввиду, это насколько я знаю code behind